# Why do I get this GRPC Error "WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile" when I start the emulator?

Tags: grpc

Good evening everyone, I have only been dealing with Java and Android Studio for a few months, can someone help me to solve this error? It occurs every time the emulator starts. Thank you

> Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
>
> Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\Sawye.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

Comment: just do `Invalidate caches / Restart...` action: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Here my scenario:* I closed the emulator with force quit. After restarting emulator, I always got this error.

*Fix:* I opened the AVD Manager in Android Studio by selecting Tools > AVD Manager menu. In the opened popup, I chose **Wipe Data** option as can be seen below image. After that, I restarted emulator and it worked !!!

[image]

Answer (score 12):

A quick fix:

From the main navbar menu
Tools > Android > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Tools

You'll then see the screen below where you can select '- Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) version 1.3.0'

[image]

I am not sure what the actual root cause of the issue is, but this patched the issue for me and may help other people.

Comment: Just opening this window gave me the option to trust the cert again. I had previously not trusted it and that led to the error for me

Comment: I don't have this installer available as an option on Linux, and I am also affected by the problem

Comment: Syfer you are right this is only available in Android 4.0 release. Upgrading to 4.0 will give you the option.

Comment: What if you do not have the `Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors` option? Does it need to be installed by other means?

Comment: Richlewis it will be in Android 4.0 release

Comment: I've updated to version 1.4.0 and the problem is back :-(

Comment: I would try the solution from irotsoma.  I tried this solution and it worked for me and perhaps some other people but the root cause is probably different from any of the solutions on this page, but by doing this it might patch what the issue is.

Comment: For me it was the checkbox "Android Auto Desktop Head Unit Emulator" !

Answer (score 12):

Invalidate and Restart option in Android Studio, followed by gradle clean, and manually uninstalling the application from the emulator finally worked for me. Individually, they didn't for whatever reason.

I tried several other options mentioned without any luck. The file it mentioned "emulator-grpc.cer" still doesnt exist anywhere. There is a keystore in that folder called debug.keystore which isn't altered after fixing it, so I'm guessing that error is just misleading about the real problem, whatever it is. Anyway, thought I'd share what worked for me since I searched everywhere for it and didn't find it.

Comment: How do you `invalidate`?  Where is that option?

Comment: Don't worry, found it under the `File` menu, but that didn't work for me :(

Comment: @Mark For me neither :(

Answer (score 5):

Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:

1. Start Android Studio

   - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
   - Click "SDK Tools" tab
   - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
   - Click "OK"

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, I restarted the computer and then runned again the emulator and it worked. Important! you have to run the app, not debug it. You can use debug after the app is installed again in the emulator

Comment: Thanks. I did as you say but the problem remains, in fact now the running app ends at the press of any button.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's preventing your app from running in the emulator, or preventing the emulator from running at all, I wouldn't worry about it.  It's something new that Google put into the emulator so it now checks for that file.  I looked at an installation which did not have the updates and the cert file was missing there as well, and it ran just fine with no error.  I'm not sure what Google is doing, but I know that this wasn't thought through all the way based on the number of people who have been having problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. The above answers didn't fix my issue. I tried a lot of things, then finally when I uninstalled **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)**  from-

> Tools > Android > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Tools.

Then I reinstalled **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)**. This fixed my issue and I was able to run my emulator again. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the strange answers above nothing solved the issue. So searched in google's issue tracker, I found someone posted an [Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151759818) about it, and here is what the team wrote in response:

> Hi, this warning is benign. We'll remove it in a future update.

So as google said: that warning is nothing to be worried, not harmful, and will be removed!

**Update:**
Issue was now indeed fixed with latest [Release Update](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/04/emulator-30010-canary.html) for the Canary Dev Channel:

> - Removed prints about certs and GRPC on startup.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add credentials for your application in console.developers.google.com i.e. credentials, clik Api Key 1 and than ADD AN ITEM in Restrict usage to your Android apps.