# How to fix Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554 error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run the emulator, the console shows me this error:

Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\User.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

And the emulator disappears after that. It is running but the screen is not shown at all. I tried to invalidate and restart, still the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306645/why-do-i-get-this-grpc-error-warning-emulatorservice-cpp448-cannot-find-cert

Comment: @aiqency I tried all the solutions provided in that post and none of them worked for me.